# What's the easiest way to prove that the following matrices are 0?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nilpotence

So this is the problem:

> Let $A=
> \begin{bmatrix}
>   0 & 1 & 0 \\
>   0 & 0 &-1 \\
>   0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{bmatrix}$ and $B=
> \begin{bmatrix}
>   0 & 0 & 0 \\
>   1 & 0 & 0 \\
>   0 & 1 & 0 \\
> \end{bmatrix}
> $
>   (a) Show that $A^3=B^3=C^3=0$, where $C=\lambda A+\alpha B$, $\lambda,\alpha\in\mathbb R$.
>   (b) Does there exist an integer $k$ such that $(AB)^k=0$?

[image: Matrices]

I know that $A^3$ and $B^3$ equal zero. That I already confirmed. But how does $C^3$ equal to zero? Also shedding light on b) would be appreciated.

Comment: Has your professor explained to you eigenvectors and eigenvalues yet and diagonalizabilty? That's the simplest way-but then again,these matrices are fairly small-you should be able to do them by brute computation.

Comment: You could also look into nilpotency of matrices as both your matrices are nilpotent. But as the above comment states, these matrices are easy to multiply and check by hand. When you figure what C is you just have to take care about the order of matrix multiplication

Comment: @Triatticus I'd just get a pen and paper and crank it out. I don't think it's worth it in this case to even bother with diagonalization with 3 x 3 matrices.

Comment: Yeah that's what I said, were they bigger matrices nilpotency would help but isn't necessary here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$C = \begin{bmatrix} 0&\lambda&0 \\\alpha&0&-\lambda \\0&\alpha&0 \end{bmatrix}$$

It's easy enough to prove that $C^3 = 0$ by solving it, as long as you don't mind dirtying your hands a little.

As for b), there's none, since $AB$ is a diagonal (nonzero) matrix.

Other than that, you can verify by doing the math that $(AB)^2 = D\ne 0$ and $(AB)^3 = AB$, therefore $(AB)^k$ is always $D$ if $k$ is even, and $AB$ if $k$ is odd.

Comment: +1 There ya go. Easy peasy-except for the diagonal part, that's a little more then a rank beginner really needs.......lol

Comment: I had a more brute-force proof before that i edited out, but as per your suggestion i'm adding it back.

Comment: The fact that the product is nonzero has nothing to do with whether or not it will have a power that makes it zero, the fact that it has nonzero eigenvalues does. A nonzero matrix can have a power which makes it zero

Comment: I meant that it was a diagonal matrix but not the 0 one (since 0 is a diagonal too i felt the need to remark that) i guess the ordering is a bit off...

Answer (score 2):

The second question is simple: $AB$ is a diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $(1,-1,0)$, and clearly powers of this matrix are never zero.

For the first question it suffices to simply compute:
$$
  \lambda A+\mu B = \pmatrix{0&\lambda&0\\ \mu&0&-\lambda\\ 0&\mu&0},\quad
  (\lambda A+\mu B)^2=
 \pmatrix{\lambda\mu&0&-\lambda^2\\ 0&0&0\\ \mu^2&0&-\lambda\mu\\},
$$ which gives
$$
(\lambda A+\mu B)^3=\pmatrix{0&0&0\\ 0&0&0\\ 0&0&0}.
$$
I don't think there is a particularly insightful short-cut to this computation.

Answer (score 1):

You could express $$(\lambda A+\alpha B)^3 = \lambda^3 A^3 + \alpha^3 B^3 + \lambda^2\alpha(A^2B+ABA+AB^2)+\lambda\alpha^2(AB^2+BAB+B^2A).$$
Knowing that $A^3=B^3=0$ simplifies this a tiny bit. But you still have to compute the matrices in parenthesis and check that they are equal to zero matrix.